# Cannot Deserialise JSON to JAVA Object

Tags: java, json, object, twitter, jackson

I am trying to pass JSON using Jackson. However I cannot get these values and I am not sure why.

This is my Structure :

**JSON**

```
[{"created_at":"Tue Jun 03 22:55:12 +0000 2014","id":473961123905937408,"id_str":"473961123905937408","text":"Bradley Wiggins omitted by Team Sky for Tour de France warm-up race http:\/\/t.co\/DHSvr1JPjm @Guardian_sport","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eHootsuite\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":87818409,"id_str":"87818409","name":"The Guardian","screen_name":"guardian","location":"London","description":"Top stories, special features, live blogs and more from http:\/\/t.co\/rrGq778cPt","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/rrGq778cPt","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/rrGq778cPt","expanded_url":"http:\/\/theguardian.com","display_url":"theguardian.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/rrGq778cPt","expanded_url":"http:\/\/theguardian.com","display_url":"theguardian.com","indices":[56,78]}]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":2267310,"friends_count":1079,"listed_count":29928,"created_at":"Thu Nov 05 23:49:19 +0000 2009","favourites_count":130,"utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":false,"verified":true,"statuses_count":67775,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"B2AFA9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/704160749\/ff996aa3bc2009a2f9b97cdd43e8b5b7.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/704160749\/ff996aa3bc2009a2f9b97cdd43e8b5b7.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2814613165\/f3c9e3989acac29769ce01b920f526bb_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2814613165\/f3c9e3989acac29769ce01b920f526bb_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/87818409\/1352211339","profile_link_color":"005789","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"CAE3F3","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":21,"favorite_count":4,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/DHSvr1JPjm","expanded_url":"http:\/\/gu.com\/p\/3pmqn\/tw","display_url":"gu.com\/p\/3pmqn\/tw","indices":[68,90]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"guardian_sport","name":"Guardian sport","id":46403451,"id_str":"46403451","indices":[91,106]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"}]
```

**TwitterStream**

```
private String created_at; 
private int id;
private String id_str;
private String text;
    //Getters and setters 
    //The following to print out what we get 
   @Override
public String toString() {
    return "TwitterStream [created_at=" + getLang() + ", id=" + isPossibly_sensitive() + ", " +
            "text=" + getFavorite_count() + "]";
}
```

**RetrieveTwitterFeeds**

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

TwitterStream stream = mapper.readValue(new File("../TrustMetricsTwitter/files/JSONData.txt"), TwitterStream.class);
// or 
List<TwitterStream> publisheDataList = mapper.convertValue(new FileReader("../TrustMetricsTwitter/files/JSONData.txt"), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, TwitterStream.class));
```

Neither of which when run print out the correct Java Object as System.out.println in the TwitterStream Class. Instead the TwitterStream Class prints default values for the values that I have asked it to print. Would anyone be able to shed some light?

For instance

```
 System.out.println(publisheDataList)
```

prints

```
 [TwitterStream [created_at=null, id=false, text=0]]
```

and 
       System.out.println(stream) 
throws

```
   Can not deserialize instance of TwitterStream out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: And the JSON in question?

Comment: Apart from the actual problem (whatever it is) that ID is too big to fit in an int and will be truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your JSON I can only speculate, but the message seems to indicate that you're trying to deserialize an *array* of JSON objects into an object. You can't do that. You can only deserialize a JSON array into an *array* of java objects (or into an object that implements Collection). If you think about it, it wouldn't really make sense if you could...

Note that a JSON *object* is demarcated with `{ }` braces, while a JSON *array* begins and ends with `[ ]` brackets (inside of which are zero or more objects, delimited by commas). When you tell Jackson to deserialize a JSON object, the first token it looks for is a `{` brace (i.e. the `START_OBJECT` token). When it sees a `[` bracket (i.e. a `START_ARRAY` token) instead, it quits and complains about it.

In response to your comment, you can "tell it to look for a JSON array" like:

```
 Foo[] deserialized = mapper.readValue(value, Foo[].class);
```

or, in your specific case, by changing

```
TwitterStream stream = mapper.readValue(new File(...), TwitterStream.class);
```

to

```
TwitterStream[] stream = mapper.readValue(new File(...), TwitterStream[].class);
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! I didn't know that a JSON Object had curly braces. Which is the problem since my JSON starts with []. I should probably then look for a way in which i tell it to look for a JSON Array instead of an Object.